Static analisys of smali source code via smalisca
I'm trying to make some changes to an android app and to do so i decided to use smalisca to understand the code flow via graph, a function of said tool, but i can't make it work!
I used a blackarch linux OVA since it comes preinstalled but everytime i try to analize an apk smali code extracted via apktool the sqlite DB created is empty (fixed size of 49152 byte but the tables are devoid of any data).
Trying to search for any pattern is pointless since the tool always return "no result"
Below i show the instructions i use:

smalisca parser -l /root/gmail/smali -s smali -f sqlite -o apk.sqlite using either /root/gmail/smali or /root/gmail doesn't change the output neither
smalisca analyzer -i /root/apk.sqlite -f sqlite
sc -c class_name -p a (most class are named alfter alphabet letters)

The tool didn't work neither when using a new apk or an old gmail apk (version 2.9.3 from apkmirror).
So i don't know what to do:

Are my instruction correct or is there some error that impair the tool functions?
Is the tool too old so is unusable now? If so, what alternative are there to help understand how the application works?


Note that smalisca has not received any update for more than 7 years. If I remember correctly during that time several new Dalvik opcodes / smali commands have been added. You can try to decompile the apk using an apktol version that was released at the time smalisca was still maintained.

Tried with a comparably old apktool version but got this warning Could not decode attr value, using undecoded value instead: ns=, name=, value=0x00001001

For Smali analysis you don't need resources, so just disable resource decompilation (if this option is available on the old apktool version).
